# ¿Como organizo los datos de un json obtenido de un servidor?

Tags: c#, sql-server, unity3d, unity

Estoy haciendo una aplicaron en unity que se conecta a una base de datos y necesito organizar la información obtenida de ella, utilizo la siguiente corutina para obtener la información :

```
private IEnumerator GetUsers(string url)
{

    using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
    {
        // Request and wait for the desired page.
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

        if (webRequest.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log(": Error: " + webRequest.error);
        }
        else
        {
            info.text = "DATOS RECIVIDOS:\n" + webRequest.downloadHandler.text;
        }
    }

}
```

y pues quisiera que los datos que recibo(nombres,apellidos,codigo,contraseña...etc) organizarlo para imprimirlos o para después usarlos dependiendo a lo que necesite, muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score -1):

Tenes un NameSpace de Unity para pasar clases a json y viseversa.
Pasa tu Json a una clase de C# y despues vas llamando las variables como te guste para ir mostrandolas. Sencillo.
Tambien podes buscar Newtonsoft.Json en Google y te va a salir mas info del tema.